# Print form in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I have a form build with ExtJS 4. It has textfields, radio buttons, checkboxes and grids. How can I make a print version? `window.print()` shows a print version but the buttons are not displayed. Or how can I convert ExtJS code to base HTML code and make grids to HTML tables?